# Swift ios relational picker views and apple dev guidelines

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, search

Right now I have a picker view that shows up when you press a label, and after you have selected anything from the picker view and hit done it will hide and the label will change to the value you selected.

But I want to implement another picker view, and that picker view will only display based on the value you selected in the first picker view.

So more or less like a relational dropdown  that you can find on almost every website.

I want to be able to select category and subcategory. But its only about 10% of the categories that has an subcategory thats why I want to build it this way.

So my question now is if this will be against apples dev/design guidelines?

Or does anybody else have a good solution on how to display a category/subcategory selector for a search form in an iOS app?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a rough sketch:

Say you pick a category from you PickerView. Your PickerView should then notify you parent ViewController that the user has picked a Category. The most convenient way to do this is to have a [Delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) method, like:

```
self.delegate.userPickedCategory(pickedCategory: Category)
```

Now, I assume you `Category` object contains an array of subcategories:

```
class Category: NSObject {

var title: NSString!
var subCategories: NSMutableArray!
//some variable containing categories content
}
```

Say you named the button to your Sub Category Menu `subCategoryButton`. You should always set `hidden = true` or at least `userInteractionEnabled = false`, because you don't know whether the picked category has a sub.

If your parent ViewController receives the delegate method that your user picked a category, you might do:

```
    func userPickedCategory(pickedCategory: Category) {
          if pickedCategory.subcategories != nil || pickedCategory.subCategories.count != 0 {
          //you now know the picked category has a subCategory
          //so allow the user to pick that subCategory by enabling this button
          self.subCategoryButton.hidden = false
          self.subCategoryButton.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
```

Then, you need to make sure the `subCategoryButton` shows another picker view containing the subCategories of your picked Category

Answer (score 1):

Check the following open source implementation of what you want.

[kxmenu](https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmenu)

Comment: Looks interesting, but that one works more like a dropdown menu and not like a picker. I have around 50 values to display, so I guess a picker works better. Thanks anyway! :)